# Make each array item a separate link

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I need help in creating links from an array. I need create a personalized link for every item in the array

Here's the code:

```
caption: function(instance, item) {
    var caption, link, collectTags, tags;
    caption = $(this).data('caption');
    link = '<a href="' + item.src + '">Download image</a>';
    collectTags = $(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ');
    tags = $.each(function() {
        '<a href="' + collectTags + '">' + collectTags + '</a>'
    });
    return (caption ? caption + '<br />' : '') + link + '<br/>' + tags;
}
```

Comment: so,what wrong with your code?

Comment: what problem you are facing? can you create an example link so that we can see your problem and attempt to rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code may be like this,you called $.each without passing an array.

```
caption : function( instance, item ) {
    var caption, link, collectTags, tags;

    caption = $(this).data('caption');
    link    = '<a href="' + item.src + '">Download image</a>';
    collectTags =   $(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ');
    tags = $.map(collectTags,function(it){ return '<a href="' + it + '">'+ it +'</a>';});

    return (caption ? caption + '<br />' : '') + link + '<br/>' + tags;

}
```

Comment: This list the array out but does not create links for each of them.

Comment: I have updated my answer,this code would be worked fine for you.you must use `map` instead of `each`

Comment: Do you have any insight on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678998/if-else-statement-based-off-array-function-results