# If..else statement based off array function results

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, if-statement, fancybox

What I want to happen is to have different URLs be provided based of what the array function result is. 
Basically, if collectTags is equal to "church" or "concert" it links to A.com else it links to B.com.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
caption : function( instance, item ) {
    var caption, link, collectTags, tags;

    caption = $(this).data('caption');
    link    = '<a href="' + item.src + '">Download image</a>';
    collectTags =   $(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ');
    tags = $.map(collectTags,function(it){ if(collectTags === "church"){ return '<a href="A.com' + it + '">'+ it +'</a>'} else{return '<a href="B.com' + it + '">'+ it +'</a>'};});

    return (caption ? caption + '<br />' : '') + link + '<br/>' + tags.slice(1);

}
```

Comment: what's wrong about the code?

Comment: are you still here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I can do it right, but I'll give it a try. Your problem is that you access collectTags again. That is an array, not a string, so you comparing it to a string will always be false. And never to use string concatination that will make your code harder to read & mess.

```
{
    caption: function (instance, item) {
        var caption, link, collectTags, tags;

        function format(tpl, binding) {
            if (typeof binding != 'function') return format(tpl, function (_, name) {
                return binding[name];
            });
            return tpl.replace(/\$(\w+)/g, binding);
        }

        caption = $(this).data('caption');
        link = format('<a href="$src">Download image</a>', item);
        collectTags = $(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ');
        function createTag(it) {
            return format("<a href='$site/$it'>$it</a>", {
                site: (it == 'church' || it == 'concert') ? 'A.com' : 'B.com',
                it: it
            });

        }

        tags = $.map(collectTags, createTag);
        return [].concat(caption ? [caption, link] : link).concat(tags).join('<br/>');
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. I think I can expand upon this